# Xcode8 Time Profile shows addresses, not code

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-instruments

environment:
Xcode 8.1 
I use the time profiler to test my program。I set my program Build Option Debug is DWARF with dSYM File 
[image]
But the Time Profiler only display Address not function.
[image]

Hope you can help me .Thank you very much

Comment: Make sure you have debug symbols and that you're not stripping the executable.

Comment: I have update My question. Can you see agin. Thank you very much

Comment: Make sure you do not have the option set to strip symbols from the executable - type "strip" into the search box when you are looking at the build settings.